# Creating and retrieving index at the same time?

Tags: c#, sql, indexing, mariadb

I am working on a C# program which runs with MariaDB behind it.
As it could be run by multiple users at the same time, when inserting (creating) a new row with 'INSERT' statement, I leave the index (unique index field) blank and let the MariaDB assign them.

The problem is, since I have left the index field blank in my program, I don't know what index number is assigned in DB. If I try to create the index on the client side, then I cannot guarantee that this is unique, on the DB as well.

**Thus, is there a way to retrieve index number assigned by DB, at the time creating the row?**

PS: I'm using sqlcommandbuilder and update function of sqladapter.

Comment: So it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: What you want is something like teh SQL Output clause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Unfortunately I have no idea if Maria DB supports something like it.

Comment: MariaDB is a variant of MySQL the SQL Server providers ("sqlcommandbuilder " and "sqladapter") ought not work with it.  The official MySQL provider is on NuGet

Comment: yes, the field is AUTO_INCREMENT set.

Comment: sorry mjwills the code is saved in my laptop at home, wish I could upload 'em, too

Comment: Are talking about getting the unique identifier for a just inserted row? An index is something quite different.

Comment: Yes, disaffected, sorry for the confusion caused. You're right. The unique identifier (probably an incremented number) for a just inserted row.

Comment: MySQL - which is what MariaDB is - has the means to get the last inserted ID built in.  The `MySQLCommand` object has a property cleverly named `LastInsertedId`,  You should be able to get it via `MySQLDataAdapter.InsertCommand.LastInsertedID`

Comment: Running 'MySQLDataAdapter.InsertCommand.LastInsertedID' after execution of sqldataadapter.update command, gives me null pointer exception. Think this only runs with real 'insertcommand' combination.

Answer (score 1):

You have it perfectly right: You can not get define the primary key in the GUI. Doing so would only get you into race conditions. You need to let the DB generate it (and any other autovalues), then return it.

I have no knowledge of Maria DB, so I can only give you the SQL related answers: Both SELECT TOP and SCOPE_IDENTITY have been used. However those are not race condition save at all. Something that however is, is the [SQL OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Retreiving automatically created data like PK's is what it is there for. And it is even part of the original Transaction surrounding the DML statement.

I could not find a match googling for "MariaDB OUTPUT clause". However I did find this:

> Other options for the statement include “INSERT...SET” statements,
>   “INSERT...SELECT” statements, and several other options.

A "insert select" syntax could be the closest equivalent to SQL's INSERT ... OUTPUT combination. Could.

Edit: Well, INSERT SELECT in MariaDB does not seem the droid you are looking for after all: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/insert-select/ It is more like a bulk insert/insert from other table/import

So I guess the fallback is to make your own insert/select combination, that is part of a manually created Transaction and lock on the table.

Comment: Many thanks Christopher. I have read all your links and it enlightened me. Yes, I've gotta use my own insert .. select and run it through ExecuteScalar() command.

Answer (score 0):

What about, using 2 sql below?

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable.
```

or

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Will be making another race condition?

Comment: If anything else was inserted between the INSERT and the select going off: Sure it will be a race condition. You get the wrong ID. It would be save if you could wrap it into the same lock as the original Insert. Then no other Insert could interfere.

Comment: Yes lock could work, but tablelock seems to prevent reading privileges as well. I don't want to block users from reading, but writing...

Comment: Usually queries have a timeout on aquiring a lock/detection of deadlocks. Something around 30 seconds. The DML State Insert **itself** already requires a full read/write lock on the table. That is by nature part of doing a insert. So it would not be a big change to manually create the lock and add a select into it.

Comment: Any DQL statement will have a implicit read lock as part of the operation. Any DML statement will have a implicit read/write lock and a implicit transaction as part of the operation. That is so fundamental to Databases, NTFS itself has both these featurs as well. I know that you can turn off the implicit transactions (you should never do however). I doubt you even can do that with locks. However both can be overruled/overshadowed if you have a comparable lock/transaction around the whole thing. You manually create them, to get "more opeartions into the fold".